# Delete elements from a hash after a matched key to the end

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash

```
graph_data = {"12 am"=>0, "1 am"=>0, "2 am"=>0, "3 am"=>0, "4 am"=>0, "5 am"=>0, "6 am"=>0, "7 am"=>0, "8 am"=>0, "9 am"=>0, "10 am"=>0, "11 am"=>0, "12 pm"=>0, "1 pm"=>0, "2 pm"=>0, "3 pm"=>0, "4 pm"=>0, "5 pm"=>0, "6 pm"=>0, "7 pm"=>0, "8 pm"=>0, "9 pm"=>0, "10 pm"=>0, "11 pm"=>0}
```

I want to delete all elements from `graph_data` that appear after the `"3 pm"` key. Output that I'm looking for is:

```
group_data = {"12 am"=>0, "1 am"=>0, "2 am"=>0, "3 am"=>0, "4 am"=>0, "5 am"=>0, "6 am"=>0, "7 am"=>0, "8 am"=>0, "9 am"=>0, "10 am"=>0, "11 am"=>0, "12 pm"=>0, "1 pm"=>0, "2 pm"=>0, "3 pm"=>0"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph_data.slice_after{|k, _| k == "3 pm"}.first.to_h
# => {"12 am"=>0, "1 am"=>0, "2 am"=>0, "3 am"=>0, "4 am"=>0, "5 am"=>0, "6 am"=>0, "7 am"=>0, "8 am"=>0, "9 am"=>0, "10 am"=>0, "11 am"=>0, "12 pm"=>0, "1 pm"=>0, "2 pm"=>0, "3 pm"=>0}
```

or

```
h = graph_data.dup
h.each_key.inject(false) do
  |flag, k|
  h.delete(k) if flag
  flag = true if k == "3 pm"
  flag
end
h # => {"12 am"=>0, "1 am"=>0, "2 am"=>0, "3 am"=>0, "4 am"=>0, "5 am"=>0, "6 am"=>0, "7 am"=>0, "8 am"=>0, "9 am"=>0, "10 am"=>0, "11 am"=>0, "12 pm"=>0, "1 pm"=>0, "2 pm"=>0, "3 pm"=>0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this way

your value

```
graph_data = {"12 am"=>0, "1 am"=>0, "2 am"=>0, "3 am"=>0, "4 am"=>0, "5 am"=>0, "6 am"=>0, "7 am"=>0, "8 am"=>0, "9 am"=>0, "10 am"=>0, "11 am"=>0, "12 pm"=>0, "1 pm"=>0, "2 pm"=>0, "3 pm"=>0, "4 pm"=>0, "5 pm"=>0, "6 pm"=>0, "7 pm"=>0, "8 pm"=>0, "9 pm"=>0, "10 pm"=>0, "11 pm"=>0}
```

now

```
ar = graph_data.to_a
ar.reject{|j| ar.index(j) > ar.find_index(["3 pm", 0])}.to_h
=> {"12 am"=>0, "1 am"=>0, "2 am"=>0, "3 am"=>0, "4 am"=>0, "5 am"=>0, "6 am"=>0, "7 am"=>0, "8 am"=>0, "9 am"=>0, "10 am"=>0, "11 am"=>0, "12 pm"=>0, "1 pm"=>0, "2 pm"=>0, "3 pm" => 0}
```

Comment: 2.1.2 should work with to_h http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h

Comment: oooho you mean slice_after yes yes it is introduce 2.2.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107322/discussion-between-vinay-and-rajarshi-das).